# Sending serialized data from android to java

Tags: java, android, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to send class variables from android device to server.

In my server java program receives requests with socket connection

I want to use xml serializer . I couldn't find any xml serializer that was supported both java platforms , jre and android .

I can use different xml serializer libraries in android and java . But i worry about two different serializer library can not read each others serialized data .

Simply i want to serialize class in android , and send to server application java over tcp connection , and deserialize received data to class again  in java .

What libraries can i use in android and java ? Or any alternative way to send data from android to java application ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out : http://www.jsoup.org/
you can also try:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/index.html#list11

Answer (score 0):

I had success using [google protocol buffer library](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). It has a compiler that generates code for several languages including java and python, and they claim it to be faster than xml / json serialization. I recently read a post that suggested using [j2me implementation](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-javame/) in android because of it reduced size.